# MS Access navigation breaks after RecordSource update

Tags: ms-access, navigation

I have a database in office 365 with multiple identical format tables, one for each year (I know this sounds like terrible design, but there are reasons). Anyway, I have a split form (datasheet with navigation, detail) to view these tables. A dropdown box allows me to choose which table to look at - select the year, and in vba I set the recordsource to the correct table. In testing I see something strange though. It works fine with the first year, and when I go to a new year. But when I go back to the first year, even though the datasheet properly updates (as does the detail), the navigation bar (on the datasheet) won't let me move to all of the records. I can scroll and see that they are all there, but out of the 470 of them I can only move between (get details for) the last three. I thought maybe that number was tied to the size of the 2nd table, but no matter how many records are in that table, when I go back to the first one I can only move between the last three.

Any thoughts about what is going on, and, more importantly, how to solve it? The vba is straightforward: `Me.RecordSource = tblName`.  DataEntry is false for everything (just viewing) in case that matters.

Thanks in advance for any advice

EDIT:  Since you asked, there is more code:

```
Private Sub cboAdmissionCycle_AfterUpdate()
    Dim tblName As String
    tblName = "tblAdmissions-" + Me.cboAdmissionCycle
    Me.RecordSource = tblName
End Sub
```

Navigation is done just using the normal navigation bar that access puts at the bottom of the datasheet.  You click left/right, type in the record #, put in a filter or whatever and it does its magic. Only its magic breaks in this case for some reason.

Comment: Suggest you try using a normal form and see if the same issue occurs. Split forms can have weird behavior. I've only used couple times in very small db with little or no code.

Comment: You obviously have more code than the code you're sharing (e.g. to navigate based on that combo box), and somewhere is an error. Since you're not sharing it, we can't really help.

Comment: June7, I made a new form, copied over the combobox and code for it, and it works with no problems.  But I need the split form because I need to be able to see both the datasheet (that I use to navigate between records) and the detail page (because there is too much data per record to see it all in datasheet view). I had tried initially with subforms but it was painful and this works perfectly... except that it doesn't.  Thanks